# Deleting a row if row selected

Tags: excel, vba

How do you make a macro, which deletes a row if a row is selected, and otherwise prompts up an message box? I made a code like this but it always skips the first if statement and goes on to the next one.

```
Sub DeleteRow()
If ActiveCell.Row = True Then
Selection.EntireRow.Delete
Else: MsgBox "Choose a row first", vbOKOnly, "Delete a row"
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you only want to delete the row if the entire row is selected?

Comment: `If Selection.Rows.Count = 1 and Selection.Columns.Count = ActiveSheet.Columns.Count Then`

Comment: or `If Selection.Address = Selection.Cells(1).EntireRow.Address Then`

Answer (score 0):

You may try below sub

```
Sub DeleteRow()
    If ActiveCell.Row = Selection.Row Then
        Selection.EntireRow.Delete
        Else: MsgBox "Choose a row first", vbOKOnly, "Delete a row"
    End If
End Sub
```

Basically you can just run below single line to delete selected row.

```
Selection.EntireRow.Delete
```

This should also work

```
ActiveCell.EntireRow.Delete
```

Comment: This code deletes the row even if I choose a single cell. I only want to delete the row if the entire row is selected, and if only a single cell, then the message box.

Answer (score 0):

Any time you want code to run when you do something to a worksheet, consider using the Worksheet subroutines.

The one you are interested in is the `Worksheet_SelectionChange`.  The Worksheet subroutines (such as the `Worksheet_SelectionChange` are always stored in the code for that Sheet.)  [Here are a list of events that the Worksheet has.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet#events)

Let's break your problem down:

1. When the user selects something, identify what they have selected
2. If the user has selected an entire row, do something OR
3. If the user has selected a single cell, do something else OR
4. If the user has selected anything else, ignore

The `Worksheet_SelectionChange` takes one parameter: `Target`, which is the selection that the user made.

Below is the code for deleting a row if it is selected.  This should be enough for you to move in the right direction.

Again, the big take away: **when responding to user input, always consider the built-in Worksheet subroutines.**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    ' Purpose:
    ' Delete a row if it is selected

    ' Check if a row was selected
    Dim Address As String
    Address = Target.Address
    Address = Replace(Address, "$", "")
    
    ' Rows and columns have the form #:# when selected
    ' Where # is either the column letter OR the row number
    If InStr(Address, ":") Then
        ' Since a : was in the address, an entire row or column was selected
         
        ' Was a column or row selected?
        ' Check if the members of AddressArray are numbers
        Dim AddressArray As Variant
        AddressArray = Split(Address, ":")
    
        If IsNumeric(AddressArray(0)) And IsNumeric(AddressArray(1)) Then
            ' Both members of the array were numbers, so a row was selected
            
            ' Delete the row
            Target.Delete
        
        End If
    
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go with this approach:

```
If Selection.Address = Selection.Cells(1).EntireRow.Address Then
```